# __attribute__((weak)) not working with multiple object files

Tags: c, gcc

I probably understand something wrong about weak:

My situation:

1. "Physical layer" with some WEAK callbacks
2. "Framing layer" that implements those callbacks, and provides new WEAK callbacks for the application layer
3. Main - application layer.

**phy.h**

```
#pragma once

void phyStuff(void);

// new callback for higher layer
void __attribute__((weak)) phy_cb();
```

**phy.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "phy.h"

// Callback, weak
void phy_cb() {
    printf("phy_cb, default implementation. BAD!!!\n");
}    

void phyStuff(void) {
    printf("PHY stuff. Running phy_cb.\n");
    phy_cb();
}
```

**frm.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "phy.h"

void frmStuff(void);

// new callback for higher layer
void __attribute__((weak)) frm_cb();
```

**frm.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include "phy.h"
#include "frm.h"

// implement the callback
void phy_cb() {
    printf("phy_cb, FRM implementation. GOOD\n");
}    

// Callback, weak
void frm_cb() {
    printf("frm_cb, default implementation. BAD!!!\n");
}    

void frmStuff(void) {
    printf("FRM stuff. Running frm_cb\n");
    frm_cb();
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "frm.h"
#include "phy.h"

void frm_cb() {
    printf("frm_cb, APP implementation. GOOD\n");
}

void main(void) {
    printf("Main.\n");

    phyStuff();
    frmStuff();
}
```

Now, if I compile it...

```
$ gcc main.c phy.c frm.c
$ ./a.out 
Main.
PHY stuff. Running phy_cb.
phy_cb, default implementation. BAD!!! <--- not expected!
FRM stuff. Running frm_cb
frm_cb, APP implementation. GOOD
```

Why isn't the weak symbol overridden in this case? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I suspect that because since `phy_cb` and `frm_cb` are declared as weak in both `phy.c` and `frm.c`, the linker picks an arbitrary one. Make one of them strong (you might have to add a `#define` to control whether to add the weak symbol annotation depending on where the file is included from).

Comment: Ah. Well, that worked. Ugly code, but works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be applying `__attribute__((weak))` to the implementations, not the prototypes:

**phy.h**

```
#pragma once

void phyStuff(void);

// new callback for higher layer
void phy_cb();
```

**phy.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "phy.h"

// Callback, weak
__attribute__((weak)) void phy_cb() {
    printf("phy_cb, default implementation. BAD!!!\n");
}    

void phyStuff(void) {
    printf("PHY stuff. Running phy_cb.\n");
    phy_cb();
}
```

**frm.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "phy.h"

void frmStuff(void);

// new callback for higher layer
void frm_cb();
```

**frm.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include "phy.h"
#include "frm.h"

// implement the callback
void phy_cb() {
    printf("phy_cb, FRM implementation. GOOD\n");
}    

// Callback, weak
__attribute__((weak)) void frm_cb() {
    printf("frm_cb, default implementation. BAD!!!\n");
}    

void frmStuff(void) {
    printf("FRM stuff. Running frm_cb\n");
    frm_cb();
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "frm.h"
#include "phy.h"

void frm_cb() {
    printf("frm_cb, APP implementation. GOOD\n");
}

void main(void) {
    printf("Main.\n");

    phyStuff();
    frmStuff();
}
```

Now we get the desired result:

```
$ gcc main.c phy.c frm.c
$ ./a.out 
Main.
PHY stuff. Running phy_cb.
phy_cb, FRM implementation. GOOD
FRM stuff. Running frm_cb
frm_cb, APP implementation. GOOD
```

To better see what's happening, try compiling the source files separately and looking at the symbols in each object:

```
$ gcc phy.c -o phy.o -c
$ gcc frm.c -o frm.o -c
$ gcc main.c phy.o frm.o
$ nm phy.o | grep _cb
0000000000000000 W phy_cb
$ nm frm.o | grep _cb
0000000000000010 W frm_cb
0000000000000000 T phy_cb
$ nm a.out | grep _cb
000000000040052d T frm_cb
0000000000400581 T phy_cb
```

The 'W' from `nm` indicates it is a *weak* symbol.

Comment: yes I know that now, you're only about a year late :PP but have the points if you want 'em, good answer

Comment: @MightyPork cheers, wish I had known this a few weeks ago when I had a similar problem!